# printing token returned from strtok or strtok_r crashes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I have tried a simple program on my linux machine which tokenize a string using delimiter (",") and prints all the token values. But its crashing on very first statement which tries to print the token value.

Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char *query = "1,2,3,4,5";
    char *token = strtok(query, ",");
    while(token)
    {
        printf("Token: %s \n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

BT in GDB:

```
 (gdb) r
 Starting program: /home/harish/samples/a.out

 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 strtok () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:186
 186     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S: No such file or directory.
```

Build System:

```
64 bit Ubuntu, gcc 4.8.4 version.
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
char *query = "1,2,3,4,5"; /* query is a pointer to literal that may reside in readonly memory */
```

with

```
char query[] = "1,2,3,4,5"; /* query is a writable array initialized with literal data */
```

so `strtok()` will cope with writable memory.

Comment: Uh.. thanks serhio :)